# arithmetic syntax error in ksh if condition

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

Part of my KornShell (ksh) script is as follows .

```
let "value=`awk NR==14 ${TEMP_DIR}/IR4723/count_part_UNVM.txt`"
let "var= value"
if [ $var -gt 0 ]
then
load_data ${count_part[$i]}
fi
```

first line in above part of script throw following error:

```
arithmetic syntax error LOADTODB/ShellsAndSQLs/IR4723/load_gen_tmp_tab.ksh[84]: test: 8
```

above script reading line number 14 from file count_part_UNVM.txt value 8. 
I am stuck in this issue. Please help me to solve issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is that a typo, or are you missing the '$' in front of value, i.e. (your 2nd line)

```
let "var=$value"
```

which I think should really be

```
let var="$value"
```

You can eliminate a lot of problems while you're building your script by turning on the shell debugging feature, i.e.

```
 set -vx
 let "var= value"
 set +vx
```

Or put `set -vx` near the top of the script and see how all of the script is processed.

**EDIT3** OR put `-vx` after `#!/bin/bash` on the first line, i.e. `#!/bin/bash -vx`.

**EDIT2** I missed your first comment, yes, line1 looks problematic too. Try this

```
let value="$(awk 'NR==14' ${TEMP_DIR}/IR4723/count_part_UNVM.txt)"
```

Note that using backticks for cmd-substitution was declared as deprecated in the 'New Kornshell Language' ~ 1995. `$( )` for cmd-substition is easily nestable and your best bet.
ALSO, note that an awk script (on a cmdline) should be presented as single argument, by surrounding it with single or dbl-quotes. (But I'm not absolutely certain you need quotes given that your 'program' has no spaces in it.) If the revision doesn't work, add `print --"value=XX${value}XX` after the assignment and edit your question above to show the output.

**EDIT** Per your comment/question, there are a few shell script debuggers around, but I never use them. Search for Rosenberg ksh book debugger, if you really want to try it.

The `set -vx` should really be called an "execution trace". It shows you the line or block of code before it is executed, then with any variables expanded to their values. That it the  typical way people debug ksh scripts. You can also add statments like `print -- "var=XX${var}XX"` to see  individual values of variables, but that can mess up your output and may required you to turn of those statments, forcing you to edit your script again.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for reply. second line is wrong. but i got error on first line of above script. is it issue  of space in value or  value  is string  which got  copied from file?

Comment: Hi Shellter , i also wanted to know how to debug script. i add -vx to my shell script. but not see changes. can you please refer me to link which explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `let` in a ksh? Here is a suggestion for your code.

**example.ksh**

```
#!/bin/ksh

#Initialize Varables
TEMP_DIR=tempDir/IR4723
var=""

initialize(){
    echo "Entering initialize"

    echo "Exiting initialize"
}
function1(){
    echo "Entering function1"
    echo ${PWD}
    file=${PWD}/${TEMP_DIR}/count_part_UNVM.txt
    readLine "${file}"
    echo "var: "${var}
    if [[ ${var} -gt 0 ]]; then
        load_data ${count_part[$i]}
    fi
    echo "Exiting function1"
}
createDir(){
    echo "Entering createDir"
    mkdir -p ${1}
    echo "Exiting createDir"
}
createFileWithRandomCount(){
    echo "Entering createFileWithRandomCount"
    orgDirectory=${PWD}
    cd ${1}
    > ${2}
    print ${RANDOM} >> ${2}
    cd ${orgDirectory}
    echo "Exiting createFileWithRandomCount"
}
readLine(){
    echo "Entering readLine"
    file=${1}
    while read line
    do
        # display line or do somthing on $line
        var="$line"
    done <"$file"
    echo "Exiting readLine"
}
load_data(){
    echo "Entering load_data"
    echo "Exiting load_data"
}

#-----------
#---Main----
#-----------
echo "Starting: "${0}" with Input Parameters: {1: "${1}" {2: "${2}" {3: "${3}
initialize #function call#
createDir ${TEMP_DIR} #function call#
createFileWithRandomCount ${TEMP_DIR} count_part_UNVM.txt #function call#
function1 #function call#
```

**Output:**

```
$ ksh -i example.ksh
Starting: example.ksh with Input Parameters: {1:  {2:  {3:
Entering initialize
Exiting initialize
Entering createDir
Exiting createDir
Entering createFileWithRandomCount
Exiting createFileWithRandomCount
Entering function1
/tmp
Entering readLine
Exiting readLine
var: 11984
Entering load_data
Exiting load_data
Exiting function1
```